# Apache NiFi vs Informatica

Tags: apache-nifi

Has anyone done a comparison between NiFi & Informatica ?

I've no experience working with Informatica tool, but as per my understanding it is an ETL tool and can be used if your use case involves a lot of transformations.

NiFi can be used for cases where there is very little transformations while ingesting data.

Our enterprise have a lot of data ingestion use cases (to Hadoop) and most (or all) of them invovles very minor transformations. So we are preferring NiFi over informatica.

Does licence cost being the only advantage of NiFi against Informatica ? What about the connectors (or processors) offered by both tools ?

Does Informatica enables you to do the things which can be done with NiFi ?

Answer (score 1):

> NiFi can be used for cases where there is very little transformations
>   while ingesting data.

Sure. It can also (and frequently is) be used in cases where there is a lot of transformation.

Answer (score -1):

The usability of NiFi is not so good !  Informatica cloud is more easy to learn e more applicable in complex projects in my opinion !

ICS is fantastic in debuging !